# Problems with finding QWebElements by tag in PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qwebelement

I am using QGraphicsWebView and trying to iterate over QWebElements. At first tried :

```
frame = self.page().mainFrame()
doc = frame.documentElement()

h = frame.findFirstElement("head")
b = frame.findFirstElement("body")

elements = h.findAll("link")
for d in elements :
    print d.tagName()
```

So you see what I thought but, but later on find that there's elements in QWebElementCollection, not in list. Please help me with iterating over DOM tree.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the exact problem. Do you need specifically a list, not a QWebElementCollection, is that it? If so, elements.toList() can be called to get a true list(actually QList), see the API: https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/QWebElementCollection.html

Comment: Thank you, yep I didn't realize there's .toList() method, but nevertheless my lists are empty...don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `findAll` probably didn't match any elements by the selector you specified, could you `print h.toOuterXml()` ?

Comment: Well it is obvious that I just started with webkit. Please if you wish, write loop for iterating over body tag...as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `QWebElement`'s `findAll` method returns a `QWebElementCollection`, which can be converted to a `QList` instance with it's `toList()` method. To iterate over a list of matched elements, you could use:

```
body_element = frame.findFirstElement("body")

for el in body_element.findAll("div").toList():
    print el.tagName()
```

Comment: That's it (pozdrav iz Splita). Now we have the answer.